# Bootstrap tab panel load data on tab click in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap tab panels in an ASP.NET page. I am setting the focus to the selected tab using jQuery. On page load event, I want to get the clicked tab and bind the content of that tab. How can I do that?

Comment: Post your code and the Bootstrap version you use.

Comment: Above is my code and i am using bootstrap version 3.3.7.

Comment: Link to the code :   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48228772/bootstrap-tabs-add-content-from-same-asp-net-page-dynamically